# Проверить статус git'а в bat

Tags: git, bat, git-status

Как в bat-файле проверить, есть ли в папке незакоммиченные изменения?

В принципе нужно что-то типа

```
git status -- folder
```

но непонятно, как это запихать в какое-нибудь условие

```
git status -- folder || echo "Changes found"
```

Код возврата вроде всегда нулевой, а значит такая конструкция не сработает...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('git status --porcelain -- folder') do goto CHANGES
:CHANGES
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git diff --quiet HEAD -- folder || echo changed
```

Comment: Эм.. Что-то не то... Попробовал новый файл создать и запустить эту команду - ничего не вывелось.

Comment: Ну да, `git diff` смотрит только на файлы которые `git` отслеживает.

Comment: А мне надо все. Я вообще делаю проверку на то, надо ли перекомпилировать файлы или можно запускать то, что есть. Пока сделал вот так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQZ5c.png